# How to view full contents if text is too large for the cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to view the full contents of a cell in Excel.

Consider the following example:

[image: Example]

The text is too large for the cell, so I want to click/hover over the cell and view it's full contents. I initially used the `Selection.Validation` method to display an input message as shown above. However, the limit is 255 chars for this meaning I get an error on cells with larger contents (I also researched a way for making this bigger but you cannot).

I want the cell and text size to remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the selection change event to display a shape with the cell value. 
Based on code from [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4593-excel-zoom-selected-cell.html)

```
    Private Sub worksheet_selectionchange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const ZOOM_CELLS = "zoomCells"

        ' Range where the cell is "zoomed"
        Dim rg As Range
        Set rg = Range("D1:D4")

        Dim zoomShape As Variant

        ' Delete zoom shapes
        For Each zoomShape In ActiveSheet.Pictures
            If zoomShape.Name = ZOOM_CELLS Then
                zoomShape.Delete
            End If
        Next

        ' Zoom only for defined range
        If Intersect(rg, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        ' Zoom only in case one cell is selected
        If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

        ' no zoom if cell is empty
        If Len(Target.Value) = 0 Then Exit Sub

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Dim oldHeight As Double, oldWraptext As Boolean

        With Target
            oldHeight = .RowHeight
            oldWraptext = .WrapText

            ' increase cell height and wrap text
            .WrapText = True
            .EntireRow.AutoFit

            ' paste it as picture on the sheet
            .CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture

            ' restore old row height and wrapt text
            .RowHeight = oldHeight
            .WrapText = oldWraptext
        End With

        Application.ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select

        ' make pasted picture pretty
        With Selection
            .Name = ZOOM_CELLS
            With .ShapeRange
                .ScaleWidth 1.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
                .ScaleHeight 1.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
                With .Fill
                    .ForeColor.SchemeColor = 44
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .Solid
                    .Transparency = 0
                End With
            End With
        End With

        Target.Select
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I can work with this - however, it doesn't seem to want to work with merged cells... any ideas?

Comment: I avoid merged cells and that would be my suggestion here, too

Comment: BTW, if you add `.Left = Target.Left + Target.Width` for the selection then the shape will be displayed just right from the cell.

Comment: Any reason why this would not be working when I copy the workbook over to a mac? The shape is appearing but filled in purple with no text?

Comment: I do not have  a Mac. So, I am afraid but no idea why this would not be working on a mac

Answer (score 1):

You could use the

```
ActiveCell.AddComment (ActiveCell.Text)
```

function of your Selection, then resize and reposition it correctly.
After changing the selection delete the old comment and create a new.
Also you would have to make sure that comments are always visible.